# What's required to save Captain Kirrahe on Virmire?

Tags: mass-effect

I was reading the [ME3](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3) entry in the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/) when I read that Captain Kirrahe would return in some fashion if he survived the assault on Saren's base on Virmire.  Now maybe I missed something the first two times around, but I know for certain that I didn't save him the third time I played the game.

I'm aware that without disabling some stuff before reaching the base, Kirrahe will almost certainly die, however, I'd like to know if there's a time component, or other specific actions that will effect this outcome.  Of special interest is whether choosing to aid the team at the AA guns or return to the bomb site has any effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kirrahe will survive if you take out the geth fliers by disabling the landing strips on your way into the compound.

If you don't, he will die to an air assault.

How much of his team survives depends on what Shepherd does with the Alarms when entering the facility - the renegade option means less will survive, but "how much" of his team survived doesn't get carried over.

[The wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kirrahe) has a little more.

Comment: [This entry](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Virmire:_Assisting_Kirrahe%27s_Team) actually has a lot more about what needs to be done.  I did disable the landing pad, but it was after Kirrahe had already died.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't matter who you choose to go with the stg team as long as you disrupt communications, destroy the satellite uplink and kill the geth air drones He'll live

Answer (score -3):

He survived in a play through to meet me at their science lab, in ME3, he's a major at that point.  In the mission to save the fertile Krogan female.

Comment: This answer adds nothing useful. The question asks how that happens.